# How can I turn off the menu in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

**I want to disable the menu in uiwebview**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable touch functions on your html page and also implement your own actions, check out this article http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/

Answer (score 0):

We have added this code

[Link](http://markmail.org/message/s2zydjckl4fjsh3i#query%3a+page:1+mid:7yifjt25xe3zokql+state%3aresults)

Within the file index.html

And it succeeded

- I apologize my weak English

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this code in your CSS file :
* { -webkit-user-select: none; }
* { -webkit-touch-callout: none; }
```